Stream hls/m3u8 with HTML
I was wondering, is it possible to make a html code to play a video file hosted in a host that use hls/m3u to stream the video?, for example, if I have a link let's say: www.hostvideos.com/e/file123 and when I open that link in my browser I must clic into the play button to actually play the video, how can I do to make that function into HTML player?
I know might be a silly question but, I use Kosmi Helper extension once Im playing the video from the link e.x : www.hostvideos.com/e/file123 it shows me a direct or scrapped link (I don't know how to say it) nad it's a m3u link. The trouble is that if I use that link into HTML code it will run, but that link expires.
So I was wondering how can I make the HTML player to somehow "play" or "reproduce" the media in www.hostvideos.com/e/file123 to can have the m3u link to reproduce the HTML player.
I want to automatically somehow the HTML player search the m3u media link of a video link to play it into HTML player.

yes it would work if the link would not expire. you need to fix that, but you don't even say what software you're using
